# Searching for multiple tags gives with "and" returns more results than searching for one tag

Tags: support, tags, search

I searched for `[phpmailer]` - There are 3,851 questions.

I searched for `[phpmailer] and [php]` - There are 4,981 results

How can this happen? If there are only 3,851 questions for `[phpmailer]`, How there are more questions when I search `[phpmailer] and [php]`?

Comment: because if you add a non tag search term (which "and" is, it is **NOT** a logic operator) it will also include answers in your search result. If you only include tags the resultset is limited to questions only. Try https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphpmailer%5D+%5Bphp%5D+is%3Aq to have consistent results.

Answer (score 4):

Not a bug.

The search term `[phpmailer]` gets parsed as just a tag, and thus you end up on the page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phpmailer, which is a page with all questions, and not a search page.

The search term `[phpmailer] and [php]` actually links you to the search page https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[phpmailer]+and+[php], which includes answers as well. If you add `Is: q` to only search questions, you get 2,611 results.

If you want to search both questions and answers with the `[phpmailer]` tag, you can add an always true search term, like `created:100y` to get all the results of the past century. That returns 8,786 results.

Comment: Note that (as @rene mentioned in his comment) the search result shows you "results found containing **and** tagged with **phpmailer php**". `and` is not an operator in the SO search, [only `or` is an operator](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching).

Comment: To further clarify, what OP really wants to search for is `[phpmailer] [php]`, which does an "and" search by default. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phpmailer+php